# Proof that $C^{\infty}_0$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have taken $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a countable cover of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by open balls of increasing radius. I was hoping to mollify and use a partition of unity to deduce that $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but this method does not give approximation by functions of compact support as far as I can see.

What is the best way to deduce this density?

Comment: Please let me get this straight - are you claiming that every function in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has a compact support?

Comment: Well in a sense, yes. More precisely, that every element of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ may be approximated by smooth functions of compact support.

Comment: This is the content of Theorem 9.2. in the Brezis book of Functional Analysis,

Comment: I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but anyway, your post needs some revision. Namely, the first line needs to be removed, or at least changed.

Comment: Yes I am, and okay will do.